# HTML5 Mobile Application Template

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am going to develop one HTML5 Mobile application, my plan is: i am going to develop the pages in web-browser like firefox and then i am planning to convert it for mobile using PhoneGap Application. I plan to use jQuery Mobile also, please suggest me the template to start with. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can check following...On JqueryMobile site's demo section you can find all the templates for your needs...

1. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/
2. http://www.mrova.com/free-mobile-template-mobi/

Also please visit nice [What jQuery Mobile Means for Developers](http://www.readwriteweb.com/mobile/2010/10/what-jquery-mobile-means-for-developers.php) article and understand what it offers against your requirements before kick starts.

Comment: I checked the templates.One doubt: Why do they use both jquery.mobile.js and core jquery.js, is both offering same functionality?.What is the use of jquery.css, is it mandatory to use the jquery.css for any mobile applications

Comment: well you can think jQuery.JS as core framework for jquery.mobile.js to build UI that renders on mobile devices... Jquery.css is used so that you can use themeRoller along with Jquery Mobile componants.

Comment: Thanks for your Updated answer.Nice article you mentioned, while i went through that article, i read this http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/, there it is mentioned that for desktop browsers also jQuery.Mobile.js is supported, then what is the use of normal jquery.js when i include jquery.mobile.js?